# Regular expression, specifying optional capture groups?

Tags: objective-c, regex

Is there a way to write a regular expression pattern that will create one or two groups based on the input text. (i.e.)

```
// ONE
NSString *pattern = @""; ([0-9]+).([0-9]+)
NSString *inputText = @"ThisIs MyTest72.56String";
// OUTPUT match = 72.56, group1 = 72, group2 = 56
```

What I am trying to get is:

```
// TWO
NSString *pattern = @""; ([0-9]+).([0-9]+)
NSString *inputText = @"ThisIs MyTest72String";
// OUTPUT match = 72, group1 = 72, group2 = Empty
```

I was thinking I could use (?:) but that just removes the group

What I am after is:

```
Text = "ThisIs MyTest72String"
Match = 72
Group1 = 72
Group2 = Empty

Text = "ThisIs MyTest72.56String"
Match = 72.56
Group1 = 72
Group2 = 56
```

## EDIT:

This sort of works, although I would like to get rid of the "S" in the initial match.

```
Pattern = ([0-9]+).([0-9]*)
Text = "ThisIs MyTest72String"
Match = 72S
Group1 = 72    //RangeAtIndex:1 {13,2}
Group2 = Empty //RangeAtIndex:2 {16,0}

Text = "ThisIs MyTest72.56String"
Match = 72.56
Group1 = 72
Group2 = 56
```

This is close, but in the case of "Empty" (Group2) I was expecting the rangeAtIndex:2 to equal NSNotFound. The docs say **"The range {NSNotFound, 0} is returned if one of the capture groups did not participate in this particular match"** does the group being empty not count as "Not participating"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this give you what you want?

```
([0-9]+)(?:\.([0-9]+))?
```

I've escaped the decimal place (which you hadn't, unsure if this is needed in your target language) and grouped the decimal and everything after it as a optional non captured group.

Should just be a matter of checking for the existence of a second group.

Comment: Thank you rrrr, I am new to regular expressions but I see whats king no. One final question the trailing "?" seems to allow the first group to match on its own, can you explain what it does exactly?

Comment: It is a quantifier that makes the previous item in the regular expression (in this case the entire non captured group) optional so that it can present 0 or 1 times.

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern:

```
pattern = @"([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)?";
```

and then in the `NSTextCheckingResult` check if the group range location is `NSNotFound`.

Example code:

```
NSString *pattern = @"([0-9]+).([0-9]+)?";
NSString *string = @"ThisIs MyTest72.56String";
//NSString *string = @"ThisIs MyTest72.XXString";

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                              regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                              error:nil];

NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];

for (int groupNumber=1; groupNumber<match.numberOfRanges; groupNumber+=1) {
    NSRange groupRange = [match rangeAtIndex:groupNumber];
    if (groupRange.location != NSNotFound)
        NSLog(@"match %d: '%@'", groupNumber, [string substringWithRange:groupRange]);
    else
        NSLog(@"match %d: '%@'", groupNumber, @"");
}
```

NSLog output:

match 1: '72'
match 2: '56'
With the second pattern "match 2: ''".

Comment: Much appreciated, is there a way to stop the initial match including the "S" when using your pattern on "ThisIs MyTest73String"?

Comment: My answer takes that into account already, your problem is the decimal is actually matching any character as it should in regular expressions.

Comment: Ah I missed that, so (\.) creates a new group which includes the "." and (?:\.) removes that group from the match. Much appreciated ...

Comment: The decimal and the second group all need to be optional as part of the same group, as per my answer.

Comment: Thank you CocoaFu and rrrr, you have been a great help in explaining this, your time and effort is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
NSString *inputText = @"ThisIs MyTest72.56String";
// Setup an NSError object to catch any failures
NSError *error = NULL;  
// create the NSRegularExpression object and initialize it with a pattern
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\d+.\\d+" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
// create an NSRange object using our regex object for the first match in the string httpline
NSRange rangeOfFirstMatch = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:inputText options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [inputText length])];
// check that our NSRange object is not equal to range of NSNotFound
if (!NSEqualRanges(rangeOfFirstMatch, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0))) {
    // Since we know that we found a match, get the substring from the parent string by using our NSRange object
    NSString *substringForFirstMatch = [inputText substringWithRange:rangeOfFirstMatch];
    NSLog(@"Extracted string: %@",substringForFirstMatch); // Extracted string: 72.56

regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\d+" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:substringForFirstMatch options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [substringForFirstMatch length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    NSString *matchString = [substringForFirstMatch substringWithRange:[match range]];
    NSLog(@"match string: %@", matchString);
    // match string: 72
    // match string: 56
}

}
```

Comment: This fails for: "ThisIs MyTest72String""